# Deleting float from dataframe column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I iam working with big dataframe in pandas. And one of the columns contains 2 data types, one is float and other is str(object).

```
           | store_and_fwd_flag |
| -------- | ------------------ |
| int      | 0                  |
| str      | 6339469.0          |
| float    | 65441.0            |
```

Iam trying to change that by using this code block:

```
convert_type = {'store_and_fwd_flag': str}
df = df.astype(convert_type)
```

Also tried this:

```
df1['store_and_fwd_flag'] = df['store_and_fwd_flag'].mask(df['store_and_fwd_flag'].map(lambda x: isinstance(x, float) | isinstance(x, int)))
```

But, when i do .to_csv iam still getting that float. So, my question is, how to drop that float.

Comment: cast it to int first

Comment: What do you mean. Can you explain with code? :)

Comment: something like this : `df['store_and_fwd_flag'] = df['store_and_fwd_flag'].astype(int).astype(str)`

Comment: When i do to_csv those mixed dtypes apperas again ;/